# .mkv to .m4v converter for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, media-converter

I am looking for a free program to fast convert from [.mkv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) (Matroska Multimedia Container) to [.m4v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4V) (video container format by Apple) on Windows. (I use [Subler](https://code.google.com/p/subler/) on Mac OS X)

Comment: As most people don't know Subler, could you please describe what features of Subler you want? Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, fast convert from mkv to m4v

Comment: Factory Format will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [MkvToMp4](https://www.videohelp.com/tools/MkvToMp4)

> MkvToMp4 can change the mkv to Mp4 without reconverting/transcoding video(If the original video in H264 format). Support for multiple internal and external audio tracks. Support subtitle formats: srt, ass, ssa, ttxt. Changing colors for subtitles. Add and edit tags for Mp4 files (m4v, m4a, m4b). Artworks and chapters for Mp4 files. Encode video for non-h264. Correction of the atoms in Mp4 files to be able to change the audio and subtitle on Apple devices. English and Russian interface.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia, `m4v` is a [video container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format) format for x264, AAC and Dolby Digital. Knowing this, you can import your video in [**Avidemux**](http://avidemux.org) and configure codecs like:

[image]

To add even more compatibility with Apple's products, you can configure the MP4v2 Muxer to add iPod metadata. When saving video, don't forget the `m4v` extension.

Avidemux is:

- free and open-source
- cross-platfrom
- supports many input formats

Answer (score 4):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) is a free and open source cross-platform multimedia player and framework that plays most multimedia files as well as DVDs, Audio CDs, VCDs, and various streaming protocols.  Including both of the formats that you mention, (note that .m4v is actually MPEG-4).  It includes the ability to convert between file formats both from the GUI and the command line.

Command line example:

```
vlc file.mkv --sout="#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mp4a}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=file.m4v}"
```

Answer (score 3):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is an open source video transcoder for Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux that supports the `.mkv` and `.m4v` formats.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)
- Allows to  fast convert from .mkv (Matroska Multimedia Container) to .m4v (video container format by Apple).
- Is CLI so you can batch.

To convert from an mkv to an m4v:

> ffmpeg -i INPUT.MKV -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -crf
>   VIDEO-QUALITY -preset SPEED -pix_fmt yuv420p OUTPUT.M4V

...where:

1. INPUT.MKV is, of course, the mkv you want to convert.
2. VIDEO-QUALITY is a number between 17 and 25. 17 will have the best quality and the largest file size, whereas 25 will have the worst quality and the smallest file size.*
3. SPEED is how quickly you want the video to be encoded. Possible values are ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, and veryslow.† Note that the faster your encoding speed, the greater the file size of your converted video at any given quality level.
4. OUTPUT.M4V is what you want to call your converted video.

---

<sub>* You can technically use higher and lower numbers as well, but 17-25 is generally a good range.</sub>

<sub>† An additional value, placebo, should never be used.</sub>

Comment: How would I use this to convert from .mkv to .m4v as fast as subler?

Comment: Subler is just a GUI wrapper around ffmpeg. I don't convert to Apple formats but if anyone has the right command please edit my answer.

Comment: If you want a Windows GUI for FFMPEG, you can use WinFF. It has several preset options for Ipod etc. http://winff.org/

Comment: I've now tried WinFF and the problem with it, just like the other applications suggested here, it's not near as fast as subler.

Comment: Since they all use ffmpeg I would guess they use different parameters.